# Error in navigating between pages in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-8.1

I get an error: `page2 is a type and cannot be used as an expression`

I'm using a button in the button click event with the following code (of course in the mainpage):

```
frame.navigate(typeof(page2))
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(page2));`

should work fine.

Comment: i got an error: 'this' is not declared.it may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: yes it's public the main page and the page 2 public notinheritable class page2

Comment: navigationservice doesn't work and i tried other 2 new pages same error